# Best Way to Have Webpack Manage Quirky AMD Defines

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-management, amd, webpack

I'm working with a very large JS module base (for front-end code) that uses AMD style definitions.  They typically look like this:

```
define('TwitterModule', [
  'vendor/jquery/jquery',
  'vendor/moment/moment',
  'vendor/jquery/jquery.ie.cors'
], function ($, moment) {
...
```

The problem is that the dependency declarations don't actually represent where the dependencies are.  They would look something like this without the directory resolution magic:

```
define('TwitterModule', [
  __dirname + '/vendor/jquery/content/scripts/jquery',
  __dirname + '/vendor/moment/content/scripts/moment',
  __dirname + '/vendor/jquery/content/scripts/jquery.ie.cors'
], function ($, moment) {
...
```

So I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to resolve these directory problems.  Namely, define the root path and also inject the '/content/scripts' part into the paths that webpack receives.  Webpack Resolve and Webpack Shims look like they could possibly solve this, but I'm looking for some feedback from anyone that has experience with addressing weird AMD definitions to keep me focused on the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you map `vendor` in the webpack config's `resolve` group?

Comment: I don't have a whole lot of experience with webpack yet, but yes, I could resolve the root path issue with the resolve config.  

The part that is a bit more problematic is that I need some logic to write to manage where the 'content/scripts' part gets injected.  I need to some kind of regex processing on that initial path to inject those directories.

Comment: Btw: That's not a weird AMD style afaik. With requirejs you usually alias `vendor` and such folders (it's called shims with requirejs).

Comment: Setting the root directory for vendor is not the weird part... the weird part is that the define statement injects content/scripts between the package name and the actual script file.  But I agree, I think I need to create a shim for this.